# What function to use for waiting?

Tags: c++, timer

I want my program to display a random number for 10 seconds; I can generate the number, but the timer doesn't work for me!!

I have tried to use this code:

```
void MemoryGame::sleep(unsigned int mseconds)
{
    clock_t goal = mseconds + clock();

    while (goal > clock());
}

...
sleep(500);
```

Isn't `clock()` the correct function here? Or do I overlook something else?

Comment: _"doesn't work for me"_ isn't a very good description of the problem. What exactly about it doesn't work?

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're trying to do, but maybe the `sleep()` should be inside the `while` loop?

Comment: The output of `clock()` doesn't have to be in milliseconds. Always use the `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` macro when comparing the output of `clock()` to seconds.

Comment: @Inspire48 -- no, he's defining his own `sleep()` above -- it busy-waits.

Comment: The loop is probably optimised out, since it's empty.

Comment: I don't think the loop is optimized out, unless the compiler has a deeper understanding that the `clock()` function doesn't have side effects.

Answer (score 3):

Every OS I've come across provides a sleep. Why not just use the OS for the given number of milliseconds? Your CPU will thank you for not keeping it busy doing nothing.

Comment: using os native non-busy wait, isn't that's exactly what the sleep standard c function does? stick to the language and avoid os specific functions, unless you really need.

Comment: There is no native sleep function in C, unless it's been added in C++11 (I haven't really looked at the multiprocessing libraries).  The sleep you are referring to is probably the POSIX one, which isn't available on Windows.  There you have to use Sleep.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to sleep for a number of seconds (10?), POSIX provides a `sleep(unsigned int seconds)` function. To sleep for an interval specified using fractions of a second, the `usleep` function provides this functionality.

The functions reside in `#include <unistd.h>`, and on most OS:s you should be able to type e.g. `man 3 sleep` to get some help.

On the Windows side, there is the [Sleep(DWORD milliseconds)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Don't busy-wait (e.g. `while(t<t1);`) unless you have a very special need to do so.

Comment: Even real time systems provide an option better than a busy wait.

Comment: Which probably reveals to you that the last time I was doing anything real time, I was programming robots on the PIC16C84 back in university :) Anyway, updated the answer.